# What are the conditions for an orbiting satellite of the earth to escape into space?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, projectile, escape-velocity

I am confused whether the increase in its velocity is enough for it to escape.
Also, will the satellite escape if suddenly stopped moving in its orbit or fall back to the earth?

Comment: Can you clarify why are you confused? Also why do you think that satellite would escape of stopped moving?

Comment: @AlfredCentauri You should not answer a teenager's question with a remark about how they should be more experienced.

Comment: For it to escape it needs to have positive (or zero) energy.  Its energy consists of gravitational potential energy (negative, zero at infinite distance) and kinetic energy (positive or zero).  If you can find formulae for those you can answer the question.  Both are easy to find.

Comment: When I downvote a question, I usually leave a comment (this is considered good form here).  For some reason, my comment for my downvote, which is essentially the same as the hover text for the downvote button, has been removed and so I repeat it here:  This question does not show any research effort.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Translating equations into the correct geometry is a difficult skill and can cause confusing for many.

A satellite in orbit is always travelling at speeds less than the escape speed. If its speed is increased to or beyond the escape speed, then will it fly off into space. If its speed in increased but not as high as the escape speed, it will just be in a different orbit.

If its speed is decreased, it will change orbit. This new orbit may intersect the surface of the body it is orbiting, in which case it will collide with the body. If its speed is stopped completely, it will fall straight down.